# The "Your Hats" view hides whether or not you have the hat on the current site, if you are wearing it

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

If you are wearing a hat, the dark blue label obscures whether or not you have the hat on the site you are currently using.

Can we find a way to label both?

[image: worn hats]

Could we possibly have the **light blue shrunk and on top of the dark blue**? Like this:
[image: light and dark blue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is confusing, but we don't be able to address it this year. I'll make a note of it for next time, though, so we can fully consider what the best way to convey this information is.